# javascript - recursively removing flagged elements from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of objects, which contains more array of objects (with the same structure) with unknown depth.

```
sTree = [{
    Tree: [{
       Tree: [{
       }],
       Leafs:[{},{},{}]
    }],
    Leafs:[{},{},{}]
}
```

it's a classic (and actual) tree.
Each Object has a reference in a DOM object (using `$(obj).data("ref",obj)`).
|this part is done|

The UI is flagging some of the objects with `obj.deleted = true`.
|this part is done|

When the user is done, i want to get back the `sTree`, without the `deleted=true` flagged items.

How can it be done?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with recursion. Loop over the structure and check every item like this:

```
function cleanTree(tree){
  for(var i in tree){
    if(tree[i].deleted){
      // debug output
      console.log('delete '+tree[i].toString());
      delete tree[i];
    }else{
      // debug output
      console.log('look at '+tree[i].toString());
      tree[i] = cleanTree(tree[i]);
    }
  }
  return tree;
}
```

You have to change the inside of the for-loop a bit to work with your structure.

Comment: `delete` won't work for javascript, since it will not remove the element, it will set its value to null